# Boundary and Interior Points?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

For each of the following sets $S$, find the boundary, $bd S$, and the interior, $intS$.

a. $S = [0,2] \cup (2,4)$

b. $S = [0,2] \cap (2,4)$

Workings:

a. $S = [0,2] \cup (2,4)$

$bd S = [0,2] \cup (2,4)$

$int S = S \backslash \{2\}$

b. $S = [0,2] \cap (2,4)$

$bd S = \{2\}$

$int S = (2)$

I'm not sure if I am correct. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: The first set is just $[0,4)$ and the second set is empty. I cannot see how you got to these results, and they are far from the correct solution. Could you write your reasoning for these results, so we can see where the mistake is?

Comment: I went off of an example in class without paying to much attention to what exactly what was going on. The example was $S = (0,1) \cup (3, \infty)$. Where the $int S = S \backslash\{3\}$ and $bd S = (0,1) \cup (3, \infty)$. Though I believe now that for (a) the $bd S = [0,4\}$. And the $int S = (0,5)$